# How to fill a UITableViewCell with percentage colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Need some tip. 
I have 2 cells in a tableview.

The first one has a label.text value, lets say 2. 
The second one has a value of 1.

The total is 3 (100%)

I want to visually display the cell with a color whom represents the values in percent.

So the first cell should be ca 67%, and the second 33%.

But how can I fill 67% and 33% of the cells with colors? If only one cell had a value then the whole cell would be filled with colors. And the other one should be blank.

I want them to look like a barchart.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is add a UIView as a background with a colour. But change the height of the view to be the percentage of the cell height

```
CGRect frame = cell.frame;
frame.size.height = frame.size.height*0.66; //The 0.66 is the percentage as a decimal
frame.origin.y = cell.frame.size.height - frame.size.height; //adjust where it should start
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.backgroundView = bg;
```

This would add a UIView to a cell.backgroundView with a colour that starts slightly further down to represent your percentage of fill.

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice. But I got my whole cell filled with the red color.

Comment: Something like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/rc8eoobbifok02x/Skjermbilde%202013-10-18%20kl.%2019.18.37.png

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you can do the math to figure out the percent of the color you want to use. Then it's as easy as:

```
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue 
                                saturation:percent
                                brightness:brightness
                                     alpha:1.0];
cell.backgroundView = bg;
```

Depending on your exact goals, you may want to play with using combinations of saturation and brightness, but with a constant hue and alpha.

EDIT:

If you want the background to be a bar graph, like you show in the link, you'll want to make a slightly more complex background view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * const CellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";
    static const NSInteger BarTag = 0xBEEF;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        background.autoresizeMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        UIView *bar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        bar.autoresizeMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        bar.tag = BarTag;
        bar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [background addSubView:bar];
        cell.backgroundView = background;
    }

    CGFloat percent = .5; // Calculate this somehow
    UIView *backgroundBar = [cell.backgroundView viewWithTag:BarTag];
    CGFrame frame = backgroundBar.frame;
    frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame) * percent;
    backgroundBar.frame = frame;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This will only give me a "custom" color. I want to make a cell like the example in the question (ref link).

Comment: The type of color is not relevant. Need the size of width of the backgroundview.

Comment: You're right. I didn't understand the intent. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to it.

Comment: I'll also note that the autoresizeMasks that I've shown in this code are key to the whole thing. If they are wrong, the size will be wrong when the table is first populated.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly mashdup's answer is not correct. It colors whole cell (I am using Swift).

Edit:

```
var frame: CGRect = cell.frame
        frame.size.width = frame.size.width*0.66 //The 0.66 is the percentage as a decimal
        frame.origin.y = cell.frame.size.height - frame.size.height //adjust where it should start
        var bg: UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
        bg.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        cell.addSubview(bg)
```

Answer in Swift.